# how to compare value on each button click

Tags: android, android-button

i have 7 <kbd>Button</kbd> that show values i want to check if value is same on continously  then do something i want to check value of `String` my is same on previous and current click then do something

How i will compare this?

```
String my,temp;
Button e00,e01,e02,e03,e04,e05,e06;

my=e00.getText().toString()+
   e01.getText().toString()+
   e02.getText().toString()+
   e03.getText().toString()+
   e04.getText().toString()+
   e05.getText().toString()+
   e06.getText().toString();

   last_week.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   {
    public void onClick(View v) 
          {
           temp = my
               if(temp==my)
               {
                do something....;
                }

    }




    });





          this logic not wok




                temp1=my;
                temp2=temp1;
                my2=temp2;
                if(temp2==my2)
                {
                //  hi=1;
                    Toast.makeText(HoyahCalendar.this, "Date  

                        are same ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                my="";
```

Comment: i want  to implement on button click check value of my is same on previous click if is same then do smething show toast"equal" how i will do this???

Comment: you would use temp.equals(my) for proper String comparison. What is temp = my followed by checking if(temp == my) supposed to do?

Comment: ok  suppose my is 5next time my is 6 or may b 5 again how i will reset my every time and store in third veriable like temp to compare previous value of my and current value of my

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have problems with the Android 101. Go check out the [developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) for Buttons.

Comment: @pash is right.  You need to learn some basics.  I can see  4 major problems in just 20 lines of code.

Comment: tell me the logic to compare string on each click with previous string